# Proof of measurability of set of all rationals

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

How we can prove that set of all rational numbers is measurable by showing that inner and outer measures are equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we arrange the set of rational numbers as $\{r_1,r_2,...\}$ and consider the intervals $(r_i-\frac {\epsilon} {2^{i}},r_i+\frac {\epsilon} {2^{i}})$ we see that outer measure at most $\epsilon$. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary this shows that the outer measure is $0$. But inner measure is $\leq$ outer measure so it is also $0$.